# Caffeine Cache always return null with getIfPresent method

Tags: java, spring, caching, caffeine

I am trying to implement Caffeine cache to avoid brute force login attempts. So that I have a cache with key = IP adress and value = number of login attempts.

I have a service which builds Caffeine cache and some methods to handle login failed and success events. If user gives wrong credentials, then `loginFailed(String key)` method is being called. However, `getIfPresent(key)` always returns null even after put method is working.

By the way, IP address comes from **AuthenticationFailureListener** component.

I have tried to Google's Guava Cache, however it is deprecated and replaced with Caffeine.

**LoginAttemptService**

```
import com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Cache;
import com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Caffeine;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class LoginAttemptService {

    @Value("${captcha.maxAttempt}")
    private int MAX_ATTEMPT;

    @Value("${captcha.attemptExpirationHour}")
    private int ATTEMPT_EXPIRE_DURATION;

    private Cache<String, Integer> attemptsCache;

    public LoginAttemptService() {
        super();
        attemptsCache = Caffeine.newBuilder().
            expireAfterWrite(ATTEMPT_EXPIRE_DURATION, TimeUnit.HOURS).build();
    }

    public void loginSucceeded(String key) {
        attemptsCache.invalidate(key);
    }

    public void loginFailed(String key) {
        Integer attempts = attemptsCache.getIfPresent(key);
        if (attempts != null) {
            attempts++;
            attemptsCache.put(key, attempts);
        } else {
            attemptsCache.put(key, 1);
        }
    }

    public boolean isBlocked(String key) {
        Integer numberOfAttemps = attemptsCache.getIfPresent(key);
        if (numberOfAttemps != null) {
            return numberOfAttemps >= MAX_ATTEMPT;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Above code, I was expecting that when `isBlocked(String key)` method is called, it should return number of attempts of given key which is IP address.

**Edit:** I have located the problem actually. If I do not put `expireAfterWrite` to Caffeine builder, it works pretty good. But I have no idea why it is not working.

Comment: Maybe you are accidentally passing in `0` as the duration? The value might be set _after_ the constructor, causing it to fail. I think you would use `@PostConstruct`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are right about passing 0. Actually I was passing 1 hour, I can see that from debug. The problem was `@PostConstruct` as you mentioned. If I pass 1 without taking it from `application.yml`, it works as expected.